# Hive serde comments not displaying in doc section

Tags: hadoop, hive, avro

When we create the Hive tables for Avro file format comments are not displaying while checking through desc table. It  displays as

> "from deserializer"

**Table DDL:**

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE bs_rev_profit_by_campaign 
(revenue DOUBLE, grossprofit DOUBLE, campaignName STRING)  
COMMENT "A table backed by Avro data with the Avro schema embedded in the CREATE TABLE statement" 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat' 
  OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat' 
LOCATION '/home/biadmin/test_data/avro/' 
TBLPROPERTIES 
  ('avro.schema.literal'=
     '{"type": "record","name": "TUPLE_3",
      "fields": [ 
{"name": "Revenue","type": ["null", "double" ],"doc": "autogenerated from Pig Field Schema"}, 
{"name": "GrossProfit","type": ["null", "double" ],"doc": "autogenerated from Pig Field Schema"}, 
{"name": "CampaignName", "type": ["null", "string" ],"doc": "autogenerated from Pig Field Schema"} ]}'  
);
```

we are using hive 1.1. Can anyone help me to know the reason.